# OneLiner conditonal pipe in bash

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, pipe

## Problem

I want to find a simple, single line way to pipe a string depending on a certain condition

## Attempt

The above code was my attempt at making a pipe conditional depending on a variable called `textfolding`.

```bash
textfolding="ON"
echo "some text blah balh test foo" if [[ "$textfolding" == "ON" ]]; then | fold -s -w "$fold_width"  | sed -e "s|^|\t|g"; fi
```

This obviously did not work.

## Final

How could I achieve this on the same one line?

Answer (score 3):

You can't make the pipe itself conditional, but you can include an `if` block as an element of the pipeline:

```
echo "some text blah balh test foo" | if [[ "$textfolding" == "ON" ]]; then fold -s -w "$fold_width" | sed -e "s|^|\t|g"; else cat; fi
```

Here's a more readable version:

```
echo "some text blah balh test foo" |
    if [[ "$textfolding" == "ON" ]]; then
        fold -s -w "$fold_width" | sed -e "s|^|\t|g"
    else
        cat
    fi
```

Note that since the `if` block is part of the pipeline, you need to include something like an `else cat` clause (as I did above) so that whether the `if` condition is true or not, *something* will pass the piped data through. Without the `cat`, it'd just get dropped on the metaphorical floor.

Answer (score 0):

How about conditional execution?

```
textfolding="ON"
string="some text blah balh test foo"
[[ $textfolding == "ON" ]] && echo $string | fold -s -w $fold_width | sed -e "s|^|\t|g" || echo $string
```